# CSS to refract image and distort following mouse hover

Tags: css, image, velo

I'm trying to replicate this (or something like it) on a Wix site:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvrddboc9me6g6t/RefractionImg.mov?dl=0

Or the "hello" in the top right corner.

https://www.andreburnier.com/

where the css:hover will distort the image, bending it towards the mouse.

I've seen a way to do it with Babel, but Wix doesn't have a plugin or access to babel.

I'm thinking a way could be something to do with an area map of the image with some sort of fish lens / skew() going on, but the

A push in the right direction would be much appreciated :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with Babel. Babel helps you support old browsers, not create cool effects.

You should use BlotterJS. This is tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ry7yksI595U

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't available with Wix (only some Npm is)  and I need it for an image, not just text. Also, I wanted it to be responsive with a hover effect and mouse area, not just all wiggly jiggly for anyone.